# Matlab Autoclick function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

Is there a way to make matlab press the enter key repeatedly for like 1hour.

I am basically trying to write an autoclicker.

Unfortunately, I cannot download the ones available for free online.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Describe your own attempts including code and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Do you need the clicks to go to matlab, or to go to an outside application?

Comment: Why are you writing this in MATLAB?

Comment: [This should do what you need](http://uk.mathworks.com/videos/robot-arm-control-system-using-xpc-target-68907.html)

Comment: Use Autohotkey, it's free and there is also a portable version (no admin pwd needed to install). And it should be very simple to do what you need. And you could call the ahk script from within Matlab.